# How can I use jersey-client with Apache httpclient underneath?

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am using `jersey-client` for a project and would like to make the `Client` use an HTTP client from the Apache httpclient librabry.

I have previously see this is possible.

I'm using Jersey 2.20.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [ApacheConnectorProvider](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.19/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/apache/connector/ApacheConnectorProvider.html). Pass an instance to [ClientConfig.connectorProvider()](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.6/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientConfig.html#connectorProvider(org.glassfish.jersey.client.spi.ConnectorProvider)) to get an instance of `ClientConfig` that will use an Apache HTTP client under the hood.

Use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's a working example:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;

import org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnectorProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;


public class Test {
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        ClientConfig cc = new ClientConfig().connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(cc);
        System.out.println(client.target("http://example.com/").request().get().getStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind illustrating a working example...? :-)

Comment: Updated with an example